# Delimit String off of Backslash SQL/SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I'm trying to delimit a string based off of a backslash, I tried using the token function but then realized that the '\' character is an escape character. Is there any way to delimit the string off of a backslash?

This is what my token function currently looks like.

```
Token(@[User::DynamicFilename],"\", 7)
```

Comment: Not 2 back slashes?  Like \\ ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIrst of all use double backslash `\\` instead of one `\`, and you should use TOKEN with TOKEN Count functions in order to retrieve the file name:

```
TOKEN(@[User::DynamicFilename],"\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::DynamicFilename],"\\"))
```

So if you are looking to extract a filename from a full file path tokencount will detect the latest occurence of backslash. Example:

Consider that `@[User::DynamicFilename]` value is:

> C:\My Files\Folder\file.txt

Since the `TOKENCOUNT()` will return `3` then the expression be will be

```
TOKEN(@[User::DynamicFilename],"\\",3)
```

And it will returns

> File.txt

Answer (score 1):

You need to put double the number of your backslashes.

In your example, it should be

```
Token(@[User::DynamicFilename],"\\", 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how deep to go with token, i suggest the following to get your result.

```
right(@[User::DynamicFilename],findstring(reverse(@[User::DynamicFilename]),"\\")-1)
```

Comment: or use Hadi's answer with token count!